# Cookie is being set.But document.cookie is null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I have set a cookie with `document.cookie`. The content settings in Google Chrome is showing the cookie. However, `document.cookie` is displaying as a blank string when printed. Why is this happening?

Here is my code

```
function setCookie(name,value,lifeTime,path,domain,secure){//lifetime in hours
{
         var c_ = name +'='+escape(value)+'; ';

            var life = new Date();
            lifeTime<1&&lifeTime>0?life.setMinutes(life.getMinutes()+lifeTime*60):life.setHours(life.getHours()+lifeTime);
            life = life.toUTCString();
            c_+='expires='+life+"; ";




        c_+= 'domain='+domain+'; ';


        c_ += 'secure=secure; ';//secure 

        c_ += 'path='+path;

        document.cookie = c_;
        alert(document.cookie);
/*Just splitted the code instead of c = 'name='+value+'expires ='+life  etc*/

}
```

Comment: Show us your code if you want any help.

Comment: Where is this script run? content script, or background/popup?

Comment: Another possible reason can be the domain name which is being set here. If the domain is cross-origin, it will not allow the cookie to be set to that origin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible problem with this function is, it **always sets a secure cookie**. So, if you've requested/opened the page with HTTP not **HTTPS** protocol, the secure cookie won't be exposed.